# How to convert 'CSV messy data' into 'JSON structured data' Using Django DRF

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I write a django api without model. I use Serializer. In views this api takes a csv and when i call the get api it gives me a data that i don't want. I want more structured. But i can't figure which function do i need to use to show formatted json.

view.py

```
class bonolothaView(views.APIView):

    def get(self, request):

        # Load CSV Data
        data = pd.read_csv("Data/ShapeUpData.csv", index_col=0)


        # Load Specific Column in Dataframe
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = [ 'Challan Date' , 'Region', 'Net Sales', 'Qty'])


        df.columns = df.columns.str.strip().str.replace(' ', '')
        yourdata= [{"challandate": df["ChallanDate"], "region":df["Region"] , "qty": df["Qty"], "netsales": df["NetSales"]}]

        print(yourdata)
        results = bonolothaSerializer(yourdata, many=True).data
        return Response(results)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class bonolothaSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    challandate = serializers.CharField()
    region = serializers.CharField()
    qty = serializers.CharField()
    netsales = serializers.CharField()
```

data.csv heading are:

```
challan Date Region          Qty      Sales 
07/03/2017   Banani           1       7748
07/03/2017   Gulsan           1       7748
07/08/2017   Noakhali         2       8979
```

```
when i call the postman it gives me output like that:
```

```
[  
    {  
        "Challan Date":"07\/03\/2017",
        "Region":"Dhaka North",
        "Qty":1,
        "Net Sales":7748
    },
    {  
        "Challan Date":"07\/03\/2017",
        "Region":"Dhaka North",
        "Qty":1,
        "Net Sales":7748
    }
]
```

i expect that type of JSON file from my csv. But the actual output is like that

```
[
    {
        "challandate": "Challan Date\n07/03/2017   NaN\n07/03/2017   NaN\n07/04/2017   NaN\n07/04/2017   NaN\n07/05/2017   NaN\n07/05/2017   NaN\n07/06/2017   NaN\n07/06/2017   NaN\n07/06/2017   NaN\n07/06/2017      NaN\nName: ChallanDate, Length: 990, dtype: float64",
        "region": "Challan Date\n07/03/2017    Dhaka North\n07/03/2017    Dhaka North\n07/04/2017    Dhaka North\n07/04/2017          A & P\n07/05/2017    Dhaka North\n07/05/2017    Dhaka North\n07/06/2017         Khulna\n07/06/2017         Khulna\n07/06/2017    Dhaka South\n07/06/2017       Dhaka North\n04/16/2018 Dhaka South\nName: Region, Length: 990, dtype: object",
        "qty": "Challan Date\n07/03/2017     1\n07/03/2017     1\n07/04/2017     1\n07/04/2017     1\n07/05/2017     1\n07/05/2017     1\n07/06/2017     3\n07/06/2017     1\n07/06/2017   2\nName: Qty, Length: 990, dtype: int64",
        "netsales": "Challan Date\n07/03/2017     7748\n07/03/2017     7748\n07/04/2017     7748\n07/04/2017     7748\n07/05/2017     7748\n07/05/2017     7748\n07/06/2017    23244\n07/06/2017nName: NetSales, Length: 990, dtype: int64"
    }
]
```

Comment: please also add a sample of your input CSV data

Comment: already added the csv

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but the columns of your ``data.csv`` file and the one declare in your ``DataFrame`` are not the same. Capital ``C`` for ``Challan date``, ``Net`` sales instead of ``sales`` and they are not in the same order

Comment: I solved the problem. actually it gives me a string. So i use json.load(string_variable) . Then when i send request it gives me a proper json format output